# how to work around Regex look around fixed length in Python34

Tags: python, regex

I would like to replace ',' with '.' only if there are more than or equal to 3 words before ','. For instance: apple, orange, pizza, will not be replaced by '.'.
I like the apple, but I don't like orange. then',' before apple should be replaced by'.'. so the new sentence should like: I like the apple. but I don't like orange.

```
re.sub(r'(?<=\w+\s\w+\s\w+)[,]', r'. ', 'ha, hh kkk ahh, ha ha,')
```

I am trying to use code above, but failed due to Regex look around fixed length in Python.

Can anyone help me to fix this? Thank you.

Comment: You probably want a custom subroutine in Python for this, rather than a single regex.

Comment: Thanks @Tom Hunt. I find 'regex' module would do the job regex.sub(r'(?=\w+\s\w+\s\w+)[,]', r'. ', 'hj, hh kkk ahh, hah,') output: 'hj, hh kkk ahh. hah,'

Comment: Aren't there 3 words before the final comma with `apple, orange, pizza,`?

Comment: @dawg the whole idea is to count number of words before comma, if >3, then comma should be replaced, otherwise, stay as is. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
re.sub(r'((?:\b\w+\b\s*){3,}),', r'\1.', text)
```

Answer (score 0):

I find 'regex' module would do the job
    regex.sub(r'(?<=\w+\s\w+\s\w+)[,]', r'. ', 'hj, hh kkk ahh, hah,')
output: 'hj, hh kkk ahh.  hah,'

Comment: @Mariano actually it did at my side. I tested with my code. it worked.

Comment: @mariano, (?<=\w+\s\w+\s\w+) after I added "<". it worked.